# Get string ressource into tab title

Tags: android, string, tabview

I have following string array defintion to set the tab names:

```
private String[] tabs = { getResources().getString(R.string.Tab_1),
                                getResources().getString(R.string.Tab_2) };
```

If I test it on the emulator and want to start the activity then it always fails to start.
But if I hardcode the tab names into the array like this:

private String[] tabs = {"Tab_1", "Tab_2"};

Then it works. But I want the value from the string ressource, to be able to support more languages. Where is the error?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: post your logcat/error exception

Comment: initialize array in `onCreate()` callback as Resources are not available to `Activity` until `onCreate()` is called i.e. `getResources()` throws NPE before onCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move your code to onCreate coz resource not available to activity until called onCreate callback like this.

```
private String[] tabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tabs = { getResources().getString(R.string.Tab_1),
                  getResources().getString(R.string.Tab_2) };
}
```